# How do I conduct a multiway ANOVA on circular data?

Tags: r, anova, multivariate-testing

I'm analyzing strain gauge data with the R package `circular`. My data are degrees transformed into radians and I have four independent variables. One of the IVs has two levels but the other three have between 3-5 levels. I have computed summary stats on the data just fine (using `CircStats`) but want to include an inferential statistical test like a multiway ANOVA. The package `circular` has an ANOVA for these data `aov.circular()` but it is for one IV at a time. I cannot find any equivalent for a multiway ANOVA using circular data. Does anyone know if such a test exists, or whether such a test is possible in any existing R package?

Here is a hypothetical data frame and summary stats.

```r
dfa <- data.frame(individual=c("C", "A", "B", "D", "D", "A", "A", "A"),
                  side=c("L", "L", "L", "R", "L", "L", "L", "R"),
                  type=c("ch", "ib", "ch", "ch", "cb", "ib", "pb", "pb"),
                  location=c("rear", "rear", "rear", "center", "center", "front", "front", "center"),
                  radian_degree=c(3.746309603, 3.875998892, 3.933472332, 3.253853158, 4.146252093, 4.522643462, 4.361775091, 3.759583424))

dfa %>% 
  group_by(individual, side, type, location) %>%
  summarise(circ.summary(radian_degree), est.kappa(radian_degree)) %>% 
  drop_na()
```

Following your lead below I have the following...

```r
dvm <- circular:::DvonmisesRad
stopifnot(all.equal(c(dvm(1,1,0.5,log=TRUE), dvm(2,3,0.5,log=TRUE)),
                    dvm(c(1,2), c(1,3), 0.5, log=TRUE)))

m_null <- mle2(radian_degree ~ dvm(exp(log_mu), exp(log_kappa)),
           parameters = list(log_mu ~ 1),
           data = df,
           start = list(log_mu = 0, log_kappa = 0))

m3_ILST <- update(m_null, parameters = list(log_mu ~ individual+location+side+type))
m3_ILS  <- update(m_null, parameters = list(log_mu ~ individual+location+side))
m3_IL  <- update(m_null, parameters = list(log_mu ~ individual+location))
m3_I  <- update(m_null, parameters = list(log_mu ~ individual))

model <- anova(m3_ILST, m3_ILS, m3_IL, m3_I, m_null)
```

However, the deviances are all the same (even when all 9000 rows of my data are included). Further, the Chisq is 0 for all rows 2-5 of output and the Pr(>Chisq) is 1 for rows 2-5 of output.

Answer (score 2):

**In principle** you can do it something like this:

Load packages:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(circular)
library(bbmle)
```

The `circular::dvonmises()` function takes care of a bunch of argument-checking and conversion, but *doesn't* allow us to compute log-likelihoods vectorized over `mu` (the location parameter), so instead we'll use the lower-level internal version:

```r
dvm <- circular:::DvonmisesRad
## check vectorization
stopifnot(all.equal(c(dvm(1,1,0.5,log=TRUE), dvm(2,3,0.5,log=TRUE)),
                    dvm(c(1,2), c(1,3), 0.5, log=TRUE)))
```

Fit a null model. Since both the `mu` (location) and `kappa` (scale) parameters must be non-negative, we'll use a log link for both.

```r
m_null <- mle2(radian_degree ~ dvm(exp(log_mu), exp(log_kappa)),
           parameters = list(log_mu ~ 1),
           data = dfa,
           start = list(log_mu = 0, log_kappa = 0))
```

We can fit other models with different combinations of factors (`+` for additive terms, `*` or `:` for interactions)

```r
m3_ISL <- update(m1, parameters = list(log_mu ~ individual+side+location))
m3_IS  <- update(m1, parameters = list(log_mu ~ individual+side))
m3_I  <- update(m1, parameters = list(log_mu ~ individual))
```

Then we can use `anova()` to do *sequential* likelihood ratio tests.

```r
anova(m3_ISL, m3_IS, m3_I, m_null)
Likelihood Ratio Tests
Model 1: m3_ISL, radian_degree~dvm(exp(log_mu),exp(log_kappa)):
          log_mu~individual+side+location
Model 2: m3_IS, radian_degree~dvm(exp(log_mu),exp(log_kappa)):
          log_mu~individual+side
Model 3: m3_I, radian_degree~dvm(exp(log_mu),exp(log_kappa)): log_mu~individual
Model 4: m_null, radian_degree~dvm(exp(log_mu),exp(log_kappa)): log_mu~1
  Tot Df Deviance Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)
1      8   29.406                    
2      6   29.406 0e+00  2     1.0000
3      5   29.406 1e-04  1     0.9939
4      2   29.406 1e-04  3     1.0000
```

This is definitely not as convenient as a canned ANOVA table but it is not too awful (I think).

The results here look wonky (the deviances are nearly identical) but I think/hope that's because of the tiny data set. Here's an example that shows that it *can* work:

```r
set.seed(101)
dsim <- data.frame(f=factor(rep(1:2, each=20)),
                   radian_degree=unlist(lapply(c(pi/2, pi/4),
                                   rvonmises,
                                   n = 20,
                                   kappa = 20)))
ms_null <- update(m_null, data = dsim)
ms_f <- update(ms_null, parameters = list(log_mu ~ f))
anova(ms_null, ms_f)
Model 1: ms_null, radian_degree~dvm(exp(log_mu),exp(log_kappa)): log_mu~1
Model 2: ms_f, radian_degree~dvm(exp(log_mu),exp(log_kappa)): log_mu~f
  Tot Df Deviance  Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
1      2   53.655                         
2      3    4.520 49.135  1  2.389e-12 ***
```

(I know this example is only a one-way comparison — you could try checking it against `aov.circular()` — but it shows that the suggestion isn't completely misguided ...)

A reasonable, although moderately complicated (sorry) strategy for testing effects in a multiway design, is: (1) test the top-level (4-way, in your case) interaction by testing models with and without it, i.e.

```r
parameters = list(log_mu ~ individual*side*location*type)
## vs.
parameters = list(log_mu ~ (individual+side+location+type)^3)
```

(2) test each of the 3-way interactions by dropping it from the model with all of them, e.g.

```r
parameters = list(log_mu ~ (individual+side+location+type)^3)
## vs.
parameters = list(log_mu ~ (individual+side+location+type)^3-
                            individual:side:location)
```

Test 2-way interactions (including only higher-level terms that *don't* include either of those terms), e.g.

```r
parameters = list(log_mu ~ (individual+side)^2 + location*type)
## vs.
parameters = list(log_mu ~ (individual+side)^2 + location + type)
```

and so on. This general strategy is described as "type II" in `?car::Anova`

> The designations "type-II" and "type-III" are borrowed from SAS,
> but the definitions used here do not correspond precisely to those
> employed by SAS.  Type-II tests are calculated according to the
> principle of marginality, testing each term after all others,
> except ignoring the term's higher-order relatives; so-called
> type-III tests violate marginality, testing each term in the model
> after all of the others. This definition of Type-II tests
> corresponds to the tests produced by SAS for analysis-of-variance
> models, where all of the predictors are factors, but not more
> generally (i.e., when there are quantitative predictors).

Comment: The tiny data set is an artifact of the reprex. In reality there are thousands of rows.

Comment: I notice that model 1 (that has 3 IV's) does not return a p-value. Is this because the null (that radian_degrees are the same across levels of all the IVs) hasn't been tested for that model?

Comment: likelihood ratio tests are *pairwise* tests; we don't get tests of models, we get tests of comparisons between models - in this case between the model in a given row of the output and the model in the *preceding* row

Comment: You are being patient and kind and I thank you. So, would it be recommended to permute all combinations of my IV's into distinct models and shuffle their orders so that I can construct some kind of pairwise comparison matrix using the resulting p-values? I guess what I assume is that I need to test all model combinations against each other to identify which IVs' presence doesn't make a difference in the pairwise comparisons. Does this sound reasonable?

Comment: In general once you get beyond balanced linear model designs (i.e., classical ANOVA), the order in which effects are evaluated makes a difference.